# Post binary chars to server?

Tags: asp.net, post

Is it possible to send binary chars feom the client to server via post ?

Should i encode it in the client before sending ?
Or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to send binary data from client to server. That's exactly what happens when you use a form with [`enctype="multipart/form-data"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) to upload files. Binary data is sent. It is not necessary to encode data on the client before sending. Another example is writing raw bytes in a POST request body which could be read on the server using `Request.InputStream`.

Comment: @darin So why would i ever want to escape a string in js ? Or encode ..?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Because most of the time it's a lot easier to encode the data and send it in a regular request than to set up the multipart request.

Comment: @Royi Namir, one particular example is url encoding. Let's suppose that you call the following url from javascript like this: `window.location.href = '/foo.aspx?name=' + name;` where `name` is some javascript variable. Now if you don't properly url encode this name variable it might break the request. Imagine for example that `name='foo&bar=baz'`. So the following url will be called: `/foo.aspx?name=foo&bar=baz` which of course is wrong since we added another parameter to the query string. The correct way would be `window.location.href = '/foo.aspx?name=' + encodeURIComponent(name);`.